# SPA - BreezeJS - Entity Framework - Error with predicate

Tags: entity-framework, knockout.js, breeze, durandal, single-page-application

Apologies if this has been already been answered, I am brand new to SPA applications with Durandal, Knockout and BreezeJS - Entity Framework and brand new to Stackoverflow. The code below is what is giving the error. The p2 is the new line of code I added. If that predicate is removed, the query works fine. But, I need this query to also filter on the expanded table ideaComments.

```
    var p1 = breeze.Predicate.create('ideaId', 'eq', ideaId);
    var p2 = breeze.Predicate.create('ideaComments.isAdminComment', '==', false);
    var predicate = breeze.Predicate.and([p1, p2]);

    var query = EntityQuery.from('Ideas')
        .expand(['ideaComments', 'ideaStatus'])
        .where(predicate);
```

The error that is being given is as follows:

Error retreiving data. The parent value for a property access of a property 'IsAdminComment' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.

Thank you in advance for any help.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming an idea has 0..N idea-comments, you'll need to use **[the any/all filter operator](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-examples#WhereAnyAll)** like this:

```
var p2 = breeze.Predicate.create('ideaComments', 'any', 'isAdminComment', '==', false);
```

or this:

```
var p2 = breeze.Predicate.create('ideaComments', 'all', 'isAdminComment', '==', false);
```

Comment: thank you much for the quick reply, it is greatly appreciated. I have tried both of the examples and unfortunately it did not work. Using the 'all' did not bring back any records and using the 'any' brought back all records, as though the predicate was not even there. In both cases, I did not see any error messages generated, very odd. I am still researching, but have not found a solution as of yet.

Comment: interesting development...  as I have been researching, I came across how you can use the FilterQueryOp.Any or FilterQueryOp.All, and that did generate an error: Reference Error: FilterQueryOp is not defined. Do you by chance know what would cause that and could that be why it seems the use of the 'any' or 'all' are not being recognized?

Comment: by the way, this is how the query string parameters looks in the response headers:

Comment: $filter:(IdeaId eq 1) and (IdeaComments/any(x1: x1/IsAdminComment eq false))
$expand:IdeaComments,IdeaStatus

Comment: Can you paste in the exact error message and stack trace?  Sounds like the error occurs server-side?

Comment: if I use the following, no error occurs, it returns all record with no filtering.

Comment: var p1 = new breeze.Predicate('ideaId', 'eq', ideaId);
        var p2 = new breeze.Predicate('ideaComments', 'any','isAdminComment', 'eq', 0);
        var predicate = p1.and(p2);

        var query = EntityQuery.from('Ideas')
            .expand(['ideaComments', 'ideaStatus'])
            .where(predicate);

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:15519/breeze/Ims/Ideas?$filter=(IdeaId%20eq%201)%20and%20(IdeaComments%2Fany(x1%3A%20x1%2FIsAdminComment%20eq%20false))&$expand=IdeaComments%2CIdeaStatus

$filter:(IdeaId eq 1) and (IdeaComments/any(x1: x1/IsAdminComment eq false))
$expand:IdeaComments,IdeaStatus

Comment: if the 'All' is used, it does not return any records. There is a data-bind error, but that is because there are no records to bind to.

Comment: is it possible that each idea has an idea-comment with isAdminComment==false ?  That would explain why all ideas are returned.